# glDeleteTextures gives error E0167 (argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type)

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &LocalBuffer);
```

and it said:

```
E0167   argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const GLuint *"
```

It is line 52.
I tried:
Passing it as `LocalBuffer`

CODE:

```
class Texture {
private:
    unsigned int TextID;
    std::string FilePath;
    unsigned char* LocalBuffer;
    int Width, Height, BytesPixel;
public:
Texture(const std::string path)
        : TextID(0), FilePath(path), LocalBuffer(nullptr), Width(0), Height(0), BytesPixel(0) {
        glGenTextures(1, &TextID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextID);

        stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
        LocalBuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &Width, &Height, &BytesPixel, 4);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, Width, Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, LocalBuffer);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        if (LocalBuffer) { //if localbuffer exists
            stbi_image_free(LocalBuffer);
        }
    }
~Texture() {
        glDeleteTextures(1, LocalBuffer);
    }
 void Bind(unsigned int slot = 0){
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextID);
    }
    void Unbind() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete texture *names*, not texture *data*. Specifically, whatever you `glGenTextures`, you have to later `glDeleteTextures` later.

```
glGenTextures(1, &TextID);
glDeleteTextures(1, &TexID);
```

I was about to say that you can free your image data immediately after uploading it for DMA transfer to the graphics card (`glTexImage2D`), but you are already freeing it. So in fact, if the code went through with some reinterpret casting, you'd get an access violation. Just don't even store `LocalBuffer` as a field in your class, it's not necessary.

Comment: Also keep in mind you're using the 20 year old OpenGL API, there's no reason not to use modern DSA object name access, especially in a class you can instantiate anywhere.